# Using Find Function to return cell address

Tags: excel, vba

I am using the find function to search through a number of different ranges for a specific heading.

If this heading is present I would then like to extract the information from the cell below. Is it possible for the find function to return the address of the cell found and then I can simply search for Cell(x +1, y) to extract the data from below?

My current code is;

```
For i = 1 To LastRow
    X = VirtMat(i, 1)
    Set TestRange = Range(X)

        Set BILL = TestRange.Find("Loss Number:")
                If Not BILL Is Nothing Then 'RETURN CELL ADRESS AND EXTRACT INFO


                Else: rpd(cr, 1) = "NOINFO"


                End If

Next
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[As per MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa195730(v=office.11).aspx):

> Finds specific information in a range, and returns a ***Range object*** that represents the first cell where that information is found.

So the answer your question is yes. You can use *Address or Row and Column Property* of the ***Range Obejct***.

```
Debug.Print BILL.Address '~~> default is A1 notation
Debug.Print BILL.Row '~~> returns row number
Debug.Print BILL.Column '~~> column number
```

In fact you can directly get the value in the cell adjacent or below it.

**Example:** To get value below the found cell, use *Offset Method*.

```
Debug.Print BILL.Offset(1, 0).Value
```